# Customize Chrome webdriver using selenium to save files without prompting to save or discard files when downloading

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate downloading files using selenium with chrome as my browser using chromedriver. When i try downloading exe files its prompting me "This type of file can harm your computer, Discard or save it". i want it to download anyway without any prompt.

I have looked into few solutions like below:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force" :False,"browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" : "application/octet-stream"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)    
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=//path//to//chrome_driver,   chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

But this didn't help it still throws up the prompt.
Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, there is no way to tell `Chrome` not to warn on potentially dangerous binary file downloads, see:

- [ChromeDriver has no way to accept dangerous downloads](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=286) (Archived)
- [Add option to automatically accept dangerous downloads](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132745) (Wontfix)

As the simplest workaround, you might want to approach the problem with Firefox:

> Also there have been numerous requests from dev community to allow to
>   disable this warning to be able to run automated tests in Chrome. At
>   the moment this is the only reason we're running our automated tests
>   in Firefox only. Really annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will look forward to implement using firefox. Will update the thread if i find a way to resolve this