# Click allow store file in chrome using selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, permissions, file-permissions, html5-filesystem

I have a HTML/Javascript file with filesystem api and I'm doing testing using selenium, however everytime I enter the site the browser requests permission to store file in device I have to click on 'ALLOW'.

How do I make selenium click on ALLOW automatically use nodejs?

Comment: Have a look at [Customize Chrome webdriver using selenium to save files without prompting to save or discard files when downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565821/customize-chrome-webdriver-using-selenium-to-save-files-without-prompting-to-sav). Maybe this clarifies it.